# CSS transitions passing through each other

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have an animation here http://jsfiddle.net/fjyL7cdw/9/ that is passing through each other in Safari. I though maybe the setting the backface-visibility to hidden would help, but it does not. this is my CSS. Thanks in advance.

```
.orniment img{
position: absolute;
}

.orniment-1{
    top: -130px;
    z-index:1;
      -webkit-animation-name: rotatefast;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
      -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -webkit-transform-origin:50% -40px;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out; 
      animation-name: rotatefast;
      animation-duration: 3s;
      animation-direction: alternate;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      transform-origin:50% -40px;
      animation-timing-function:ease-in-out; /* REG */
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.orniment-2{
    top: -240px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 10;
      -webkit-animation-name: rotateslow;
      -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
      -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
      -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      -webkit-transform-origin:50% -40px;
      -webkit-animation-timing-function:ease-in-out; /* WEBKIT */
      animation-name: rotateslow;
      animation-duration: 5s;
      animation-direction: alternate;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
      transform-origin:50% -40px;
      animation-timing-function:ease-in-out; 
      -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
      backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: So what do you want the animation to do? For the image in front NOT to hide the one in the back?
After reading your question I assumed you wanted the back to be hidden by the front, but that's exactly what is happening.

Comment: In Chrome, it works fine, but not in Safari. In Safari the images seem to pass through each other.